# Select2 multiple

Tags: select2

Estoy intentando usar select2 pero no está funcionando correctamente, queda de la siguiente manera (sin mostrar el campo con las opciones seleccionadas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería verse de esta manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código html es este

```
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Select2</h4>
                    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        ...
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

y el script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

Estoy usando junto con CDN.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Alguna idea de qué podría ser el problema?

Comment: en que manera estás acomodando tus scripts? al final de documento? tu script lo estás poniendo después de importar la librería?

Comment: El script estoy colocando al final, y estoy llamando a la librería en el layout

Comment: ¿Y el problema cuál es? ¿Cómo debería verse?

Comment: @A.Cedano ya agregue como deberia verse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema debe estar ocurriendo debido a la forma en que agregas las librerías, o a que está habiendo interferencias con otras librerías.

Aquí se agrega en primer lugar la librería jQuery, y a continuación las dos librerías de select2. Las tres librerías en el `head` y el código funciona del modo esperado, como demuestra el snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    width: '300px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h4>Select2</h4>
  <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

no estás importando el css de bootstrap theme

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/select2-bootstrap4.css">
```

Podes descargar el .css aquí
[select2-bootstrap4-theme](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme)